# using dynamic type as argument to it's own basetype

Tags: c#, .net, f#, reflection.emit

I'm trying to write some code generating a type at runtime. I have an interface I need to implement but the constraint is causing me some difficulties.

As has been noted in the comments, yes the interface *looks* like and endless recursion but is not. It compiles just fine

The interface looks similar to:

```
interface IFoo<T> where T : IFoo<T>{
   T MyProperty{get;}
}
```

When I the try to define my dynamic type using ModuleBuilder I have an issue:

```
TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType(
            "typename",
             TypeAttributes.Public,typeof(object),new[]{...});
```

have do I get to pass in a IFoo where T is the type I'm trying to define?

The code above in C# but answers in F# that let's me dynamically construct `class SomeType : IFoo<SomeType>` will do just fine as well

Answer that uses a base type instead of an interface is also valid (as the title suggests). I.e.

```
 TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType(
                "typename",
                 TypeAttributes.Public,...,null);
```

where .. is of `SomeType<T>` and T is the type being defined

**EDIT:**
As an example of this when written in code could be:

```
    public interface ISelf<T> where T : ISelf<T>
    {
        T Prop { get; }
    }

    public class SelfBase<T> : ISelf<T> where T : SelfBase<T>{
        public T Prop  { get { return (T)this; } }
    }

    public class FooBar : SelfBase<FooBar>{
        public void Bar(){
            Prop.NonInterfaceMethod();
        }

        public void NonInterfaceMethod(){}
    }
```

That piece of code does indeed compile.

Comment: Does this even work? This interface definition looks like an endless recursion to me...

Comment: Your interface looks very strange. T is an IFoo<T>, where again T is an IFoo<T>, and so on. This looks as if it will produce some sort of overflow because you cannot specify T. Keyword: recursion

Comment: @Daniel it does indeed work. I started out compiling a static version before I tryed the dynamic.

Comment: @Christian see it as a version of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern. It does indeed compile

Comment: I would say it is not possible with the `ModuleBuilder` and `TypeBuilder` classes as their API needs a `Type` for the interface to implement and you don't have one until you call `CreateType` on the type builder at which point it is too late...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the `SetParent` method on the `TypeBuilder`.  Here's how to do it in F#:

```
open System
open System.Reflection
open System.Reflection.Emit

type SelfBase<'t when 't :> SelfBase<'t>> =
    member x.Prop = x :?> 't

type Foo = class
    inherit SelfBase<Foo>
end

let ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(AssemblyName("test"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run)
let mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule("test")
let tb = mb.DefineType("typename", TypeAttributes.Public)
tb.SetParent(typedefof<SelfBase<Foo>>.MakeGenericType(tb))
let ty = tb.CreateType()

// show that it works:
let instance = System.Activator.CreateInstance(ty)
let prop = instance.GetType().GetProperties().[0].GetValue(instance, null)
let same = (prop = instance)
```